# How to read an object from an array that has only 0 index in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
[
  {
    "first" : {
      "email" : "abofahad.en@gmail.com"
    },
    "second" : {
      "email" : "aaa@gmail.com"
    }
  }
]
```

as you know first and second is inside index 0 but how can read them using map without using like

```
user.map(c=>c.first.email)
```

Comment: I think the structure of data you posted here is wrong. Arrays cannot have named keys, they only have numbered keys called indexes/indices

Comment: You can't as it is not a valid array.

Comment: this structure of data i got it from firebase not from me

Comment: this structure of data i got it from firebase not from me

Comment: This is neither a valid array nor a valid object. I think the first square brackets should be `{` instead of `[`

Comment: yes it's but i need it in the array method to use map

Comment: You couldn't convert obj to array by this method!

Comment: i don't understand what is expected output ?

Comment: let't  approve my edit if your data contains object inside array. if not  please add valid data structure

Comment: user = {
    "first": {
      "email": "abofahad.en@gmail.com"
    },
    "second": {
      "email": "aaa@gmail.com"
    }
}

print(user["first"])
print(user["first"]["email"])

Answer (score 1):

```
let users = [
  {email: "abofahad.en@gmail.com"},
  {email: "aaa@gmail.com"}
]
```

// .map() return new array

```
let user = users.map((item) => item.email)
console.log(user)
console.log(user[0])
console.log(user[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

It's no less clunky, but `Object.keys()` will achieve the same results

```js
let obj = {
  "user": {
    "first": {
      "email": "abofahad.en@gmail.com"
    },
    "second": {
      "email": "aaa@gmail.com"
    }
  }
}

let res = Object.keys(obj.user).map(el => {
  return obj.user[el].email
})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: @Aziz one problem I saw with your code it the outer array should have an object inside of it. `first` and `second` are keys, javascript arrays don't have keys.

Comment: it's from firebase not from me

Comment: @Aziz unfortunately it's not valid Javascript so it will always throw an error. You should research objects vs. arrays in javascript

Comment: {
   "user":{
  
    "first" : {
      "email" : "abofahad.en@gmail.com"
    },
    "second" : {
      "email" : "aaa@gmail.com"
    }
 }
} it basically like that